# Very strange/inconsistent behaviour when making a GET request to a external api

Tags: rest, angular

I am busy with a angular4 web app that uses the youtubeInMp3 API.  Everything works as it should when downloading mp3 files using the API however it doesn't work for all videos, I'm not sure which videos give the issue, I've noticed that it often happens when  the YouTube video ID contains the _ character.  when it does I get the below error...  I know that the issue isn't with the video as it works when I test it http://www.youtubeinmp3.com  I've tried urlEncoding the id before passing it to the API, replacing _ with - and replacing _ with %20 with no success.  Any idea what might be going wrong here/how I can go about fixing it?

My error (from chrome developer console)

> core.es5.js:3046 Angular is running in the development mode. Call
>   enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>
> main.bundle.js:368 id: t0sS60Jx51c main.bundle.js:788 url
>   main.bundle.js:789
>   http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0sS60Jx51c
>   main.bundle.js:376 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
>   0
>       at Object.parse ()
>       at Response.Body.json (vendor.bundle.js:37736)
>       at MapSubscriber.project (main.bundle.js:791)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (vendor.bundle.js:22171)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (vendor.bundle.js:242)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (vendor.bundle.js:38165)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.576.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2496)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:5501)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.576.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2495)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.576.Zone.runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2263)

When I make this request that gives me an error in the insomnia REST client I get the following response:

metahttp-equiv="refresh" content="0" url="http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0sS60Jx51cautostart=1n=x="

An example of a response successful request to the youtubeInMp3 Api, the id logged in the console is the YouTube video id:

> id: bjLorSJAB70 main.bundle.js:788 url main.bundle.js:789
>   http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjLorSJAB70
>   main.bundle.js:371 Objectlength: "199"link:
>   "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=fOzuoPTm06oBoLw3aidWejXF7Yc2JB3T&e=33"title:
>   "Santo Daime EU CHAMO A CURA"**proto**: Object main.bundle.js:373
>   http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=fOzuoPTm06oBoLw3aidWejXF7Yc2JB3T&e=33

My code:

```
//function that passes the video id to a restService for downloading:
download(id: string) {
        console.log("id: " + id);     
            this.restService.yDownload(id)
        .subscribe(
        (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            let url = res.link;
            console.log(url);
            window.location.href = `${url}target="_blank"`;
        }, (res) => {
            console.log(res)
        });
    }

    //rest service function for getting the download link from youtubeInMp3 api
    yDownload(id: string) : Observable<any> {
    let params = [
    `format=JSON`,
    `video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${id}`
    ].join('&');
    let queryUrl = `${this.Y_DOWNLOAD_URL}?${params}`;
    console.log("url");
    console.log(queryUrl);
    return this.http.get(queryUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((err: any) => Observable.throw(err || 'server error'));
}
```

Comment: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 means that html page is returned instead of valid json. This isn't angular question. You could isolate the problem by making a request manually. Since this is API bug, consider dealing with their support or find an alternative if you're not up to this. I don't see how SO can help here.

Comment: @user2094257  it works fine when using the insomnia REST client so it's definitely not an issue with the API.

Comment: The link you've posted, http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0sS60Jx51c , it responds with html. I don't see what can be done here.

Comment: It seems like after I added that link to the download textfield on their site and downloaded it there first now it works on my side.  So i'm guessing they store it somehow and if it hasn't been downloaded before they first have to download it to get a link...